# P5js I want code to run for a sustained amount of time after keyIsPressed

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am a complete beginner and I am working inside a custom p5js framework for a school project. We are working on a clock.

Basically, I want a piece of code to stay active for ~5 seconds after using the keyIsPressed feature. I've tried just about every solution I can possibly think of, for loops, while loops. Even my teacher hasn't been able to help me solve this.

The kicker is we are not allowed to use the native p5js seconds. Since we are working inside the clock framework for school they have made custom hour, minute, second objects. I feel like these will be the key but I just can figure it out.

```
 if((keyIsPressed === true) &&  (keyCode === ENTER)) {
  let timer = obj.seconds;

    if(timer < (obj.seconds + 10)){
      fill(255, 0, 0);
      ellipse(700, 250, 300, 300);
    } else {
      fill(0);
      ellipse(700, 250, 300, 300);
    }
  }
```

Is there a way where I can sustain the code inside this if statement instead of it just running *while* the key is held?

This is probably a silly question but I just couldn't find an answer anywhere, Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do their custom hour, minute, second objects look like?

Comment: If you have to use their custom time objects, think about how you would use `setTimeout` or `setInterval` to check if 5 seconds have passed and use that solution with the custom time objects instead. Using for/while loops would just lock up the animation and probably not get you the result you want (since it's for a school project).

Comment: @phentnil The issue I am having with the custom obj.seconds is that it is constantly ticking from 0 - 59. The key press could happen at any point in that minute so how do I tell it to do that animation for 10 of those seconds. I'm trying hard to think of a solution to this but it feels just out of my field of view

Comment: So, when the button is pressed, save the hour, minutes, and seconds but modify minutes to `minutes + 5` (account for rolling over into the next hour) and when the time object values are equivalent, change the `isActive` to false. Does that sound doable? Try writing that into code and edit your post if it doesn't work.

Comment: @phentnil I have edited the code in my post to what I have at the moment, It's still only turning the circle red while I hold the enter key down

Comment: So, does the time object measure the time from the start of the code? Or the current time in hours, minutes, seconds? You'll want to create the `timer` variable outside of the `draw` function (if you're able to do so) in order to keep track of the last time saved.

Comment: Also: *"The issue I am having with the custom obj.seconds is that it is constantly ticking from 0 - 59."* You'll want to account for rolling over to the next minute (and possibly the next hour). You're on the right track, though. The solution will depend upon whether you are able to create variables outside of the [tag:p5js] `setup` and `draw` functions in addition to not using the built-in `second()` function.

Comment: This seems like a possible [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/399876), where OP assumes the way to solve problem of creating a ticking clock is "sustaining" the function somehow. But there's probably a better way to do it that can't be shared because there's not enough context or a [mcve].